# Java Gson: Deserializing complex JSON string

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Consider a complex JSON string

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "1",
    "CLUSTERS": {
      "3": {
        "name": "3",
        "SUBCLUSTERS": {
          "6": {
            "INSTANCES": [
              {
                "SERVER": "4",
                "ID": "133",
                "DESCR": "Hi"
              },
              {
                "SERVER": "5",
                "ID": "6",
                "DESCR": "Lo"
              },            
            "name": "6"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that has hundreds of `CLUSTERS` and `SUBCLUSTERS`.  How would you go about de-serializing such a complex structure with Java.  Is there a way to de-serialize without having to create classes like `public class Cluster3` and `public class Subcluster6`?

So far I have these classes:

**Cluster.java**

```
public class Cluster {

    @SerializedName("SUBCLUSTERS")
    private Subcluster subCluster;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Subcluster.java**

```
public class Subcluster {

    @SerializedName("INSTANCES")
    private InstanceArray instanceArray;
}
```

**Site.java**

```
public class Site {

    @SerializedName("CLUSTERS")
    private Cluster cluster;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Instance.java**

```
public class Instance {

    @SerializedName("SERVER")
    private String serverName;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String instanceId;

    @SerializedName("DESC")
    private String description;
}
```

**InstanceArray.java**

```
public class InstanceArray {

    @SerializedName("INSTANCES")
    private List<Instance> instance;
}
```

But I don't think I am accounting for the actual `CLUSTERS` and `SUBCLUSTERS` objects themselves, such as `3` and `6`.  How can I do this without making a class for each individual CLUSTER and SUBCLUSTER object since that wouldn't be plausible?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is create a class that implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer. There is also com.google.gson.JsonSerializer for going in the other direction.

The interface is generic, so you have give it a custom class that represents the Java storage of the data. Then in the method, you parse the JSON and build up the object.

This allows you to write a custom deserializer without having to make various Java POJO classes.

I used this approach to deserialize some tricky JSON in my application recently.

This document explains how to write custom deserializers: [GSON Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will probably take me a long time to read through all of that and I'll still be lost since all of the code examples are for simple strings... but I'll give it a shot.